# How to calculate additional statistics in a multihop broadcast protocol (flooding) in OMNeT++, Veins, INET and SUMO?

Tags: broadcast, omnet++, veins, inet, sumo

I am simulating a multihop broadcast protocol based on flooding using OMNeT++-4.6, Veins-4a2, SUMO-0.21.0 and Inet-3.3.0. I am collecting statistics for different parameters, as depicted in image below.[Statistics collected for node[41]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyK4U.jpg)

However, I want to calculate some additional statistics such as end-to-end delay, total packet loss and total packets received successfully.
Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.
Thank you all!

Comment: Part 5 of the OMNeT++ TicToc Tutorial shows how to collect statistics: https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part5/ Signals are not available in OMNeT++ 4.6, but the cOutVector and scalars can be used to solve your problem.

Comment: But I think I am using channels for collecting some of the statistics. Please have a look at the following .ned file that I am using. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XRtZsnxJAIATuBK0pdQva3Gwmkyz0EBi

Comment: In your Flooding.cc file, there should be some code which triggers signals. Something like "emit(beaconReceivedSignal, SOMEVALUE);"
Chapter 5.3 of the TicToc Tutorials shows how to do this

Comment: I know about signals. I know how to display results. What I am confused with is how can I actually calculate end-to-end delay. Actually, I want to know how can i get the packet send time and packet reception time for every message/packet transmitted?